# Exercises for Neck Pain

Tags: pain, neck

I've had non-specific, subclinical neck pain for about four years (otherwise, I'm in great physical shape.) I'm sure the pain is because of my computer use - like I'm doing at this moment.  I'm wondering what exercises other people might have found to help relieve or prevent neck pain?  Are you doing exercises for cervical strengthening, endurance, motor control? Are you doing exercises for your cervical flexors, extensors, or both?  Are you getting manual therapy? Are you stretching?  Are you using elastic bands? What works?

Comment: Existing pains should not be treated with advice from the Internet. You should see a qualified doctor or physical therapist.

Comment: While I agree with Alec’s comment, I also suffer tremendously from this due to a mild disc herniation. It’s chronic and I can understand the desperation. For me, there are three “biggies” that will give me 24-72 hours of relief: distance swimming (2-3k); lifting weights - especially targeting upper back (Lats, traps, rotator cuff, delts - rear delts especially, etc), with a primary focus on strength - Personally, I love strict form barbell overhead press for my neck; 24/7 focus on posture. Your posture probably sucks and you don’t even know it. I also get massages and foam roll my upper back.

Comment: There can be 3 reasons for neck pain associated with computer work: 1) too much time 2) bad posture 3) improper use -working at the computer when you should do something else. Without knowing if pain is due to tense muscles or herniated disc, for example, I wouldn't do any specific exercises, because they can do more harm than good. So, the first thing is prevention. If this does not help, you may want to get an _exact_ diagnosis from a doctor.